# Erro IO Exception ao tentar manipular um arquivo

Tags: java, arquivo, exceção

Eu já compilei e executei o programa no NetBeans e funciona normalmente, mas quando vou executá-lo pelo terminal sempre da o erro de IO Exception. Existe alguma outra maneira de ler arquivos sem que ocorra esse erro?

Minha função para ler arquivo:

```
public static ArrayList<String> leArquivo(String nomeArq) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        int cont = 1;
        ArrayList<String> frames = new ArrayList<>();
        String linha = "";
        FileReader arq = new FileReader(nomeArq.trim());
        BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);
        while (linha != null) {
            linha = lerArq.readLine();
            frames.add(cont + "&" + linha + "\n");
            cont++;
        }

        return frames;
    }
```

chamada da função:

```
try{
    frame = leArquivo("sw.txt");
}catch (IOException e) {
    Logger.getLogger(ServidorTeste.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Sempre que eu chamo a função, cai na exceção de IO Exception:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A solução abaixo não lhe atendeu?

Comment: Me atendeu sim, obrigada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não é possível garantir que o arquivo sempre existirá, interessante checar sua existência antes de manipula-lo:

```
try{

    String path = "sw.txt";

   if(new File(path).exists()) {
        frame = leArquivo(path);
    }
}catch (IOException e) {
    Logger.getLogger(ServidorTeste.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

E caso queira criar o arquivo quando ele não existir, basta utilizar o método `createNewFile()`:

```
try{

    String path = "sw.txt";
    File file = new File(path);

   if(!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    frame = leArquivo(path);

}catch (IOException e) {
    Logger.getLogger(ServidorTeste.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Deu certo! Descobri também que deveria trocar meus arquivos de pasta pelo modo que estava executando no terminal

Comment: @Éowyn sim, precisa informar um caminho absoluto(Tipo C:\caminho) senão fora do netbeans pode não encontrar o arquivo.